# The view's frame on iOS 8 and 7 are different

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

The UI objects in my app are almost generated by code.
Usually, I calculate the object's frame from it's super view's frame
(i.e. self.view.frame @ view controller).
My app uses landscape mode only.

After updating my phone/IDE to iOS 8/Xcode 6 GM, the objects' size/position are wrong.

In iOS 7, the super view's frame size was {568, 320}.
It's {320, 568} now.

Should I simply use NSFoundationVersionNumber to determine the *true* super view's frame?

Comment: it's new behaviour of ios 8, now they begun to logically respect view size. I mean they return you concrete dimension.

Comment: It seems then that we can't use the new universal storyboard for iOS 7 as well as iOS 8 apps. Are we supposed to have a separate storyboard for each iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this for more detail:
and you can manage size using size classes

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014205-SW30